# Refer to a previous calculation in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if there's a way to refer to a previous part of a calculation in the same statement.

For example:

```
(random.randint(1, 2) * 10) + ... ## Is there a way to refer to the random number 
                                  ## previously  calculated, which will go in
                                  ## the space of the ellipsis?
```

I know this could be done using a variable, but ideally I'm looking for a one-liner.

Thanks!

Comment: Nope. This is why functions were made though.

Comment: I'd say this is why variables were made: to keep and reuse calculated values.

Comment: No, that's what variables are for.

Comment: It's possible in Ruby: `(x = rand(2) + 1) * 10 + x ** 2` but I don't think there's anything equivalent in Python, since Python assignment is a statement.

Comment: @EricDuminil Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are up to a, rather unreadable, one-liner that uses `(random.randint(1, 2) * 10)` only once, you can do something like this:

```
[x + y for x, y in [[(random.randint(1, 2) * 10)] * 2]][0]
```

Clearly, using a variable is the preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is **No, there is no way.**.

This is what I mean with: this is what functions are for. *(Ofc you could say that this is what variables are for too - but it goes hand in hand)*.

```
import random

func = lambda x: x*10 + x  # function alt1 

def func(x):               # function alt2
    return x*10 + x
```

And call it with:

```
func(random.randint(1, 2)) # and this can now in turn be used inside formulas
```

---

For instance you can now do:

```
def calculate_something(x):
    return x*x

calculate_something(func(random.randint(1, 2)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is essentially using variables. :( Anyway, thanks! +1

Comment: @AdiC Yes, basically. There is no work-around. Try to keep it simple and readable

Comment: @NickA This is all conceptual, just some random stuff.

Comment: @Anton true, admittedly a more realistic example from OP would be helpful as both here can be solved without referencing the value more than once

Comment: @NickA I agree with `x*11` :) but this was the first example that came to mind